# Django CMS Show_Menu Example wont work for multi-level menu

Tags: django, django-cms

base.html:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                   {% show_menu 0 1 100 100 "menu.html" %}
                </ul>

            </div>
```

menu.html:

```
{% load i18n menu_tags cache %}
{% for child in children %}
    <li class="child{% if child.selected %} selected{% endif %}{% if child.ancestor %} ancestor{% endif %}{% if child.sibling %} sibling{% endif %}{% if child.descendant %} descendant{% endif %}{% if child.children %} dropdown{% endif %}">

        <a {% if child.children %}class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"{% endif %} href="{{ child.attr.redirect_url|default:child.get_absolute_url }}">
            <span>{{ child.get_menu_title }}</span>{% if child.children|length %}<span class="caret"></span>{% endif %}
        </a>

        {% if child.children %}
            <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                {% show_menu from_level to_level extra_inactive extra_active "dropdownmenu.html" "" "" child %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}

    </li>
    {% if class and forloop.last and not forloop.parentloop %}{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

dropdownmenu.html:

```
{% load i18n menu_tags cache  %}
{% for child in children %}
    <li {% if child.children %}class="dropdown-submenu"{% else %} {% endif %}>
        <a tabindex="-1" href="{{ child.attr.redirect_url|default:child.get_absolute_url }}">{{ child.get_menu_title }}</a>
        {% if child.children %}
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                {% show_menu from_level to_level extra_inactive extra_active "dropdownmenu.html" "" "" child %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}

    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Submenu doesn't show up

Comment: you're passing `child` to the dropdownmenu but then try to iterate through `children` which isn't defined.  You probably need to do `{% for child in child.children %}` in your dropdownmenu.html template.

Comment: Tried that. But doesn't work. I don't see the submenu under dropdownmenu

Answer (score 0):

I was just having this problem.  I published the pages, and then I could see them in the rendered menu.